# Simple probability problem.

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

$X$ ~ $U(0,1)$ and $Y$~U$(0,1)$ are two indenpendent variables. Get Pr ( Y > X).

> **NOW** what i don't understant in this problem is **how** you set the limits of integration. I heard that you must set one fixed and let the other vary, but in details what's the meaning behind this? ps. U is the uniform distribution

Comment: Y is also uniform distribution? or normal distribution?

Comment: is also uniform, thanks for noticing @MoonKnight! I've edited it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First method**

Consider the domain $D = \{(x,y) \in [0,1]^2 : x < y\}$. By definition,
$$
\Pr\{Y > X\} = \iint_Ddxdy.
$$
Using the Fubini theorem, we can split this double integral into 
$$
\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^11_{\{x < y\}}dx  \right)dy=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^y dx\right)dy = \int_0^1y\,dy = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
In an intuitive manner, it is the same as following these steps:

- fix the value of $Y=y$,
- compute $\Pr\{y > X\}$,
- integrate the result with respect to $y$.

To be more precise, the corresponding formula is
$$
\Pr\{Y > X\} = \int_0^1\Pr\{y > X\}dy.
$$

This is a *very simple* case of "desintegration of measure", also known as "conditional expectation" in Probability Theory.

**Alternative method**

Notice that $\Pr\{X=Y\}=0$ and $\Pr\{Y > X\} = \Pr\{X > Y\}$ by symmetry, so that
$$
1 = \Pr\{X=Y\} + \Pr\{Y > X\} + \Pr\{X > Y\} = 2\Pr\{Y > X\}
$$
which entails $\Pr\{Y > X\} = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks very much for such beautiful answer @Siméon!